# What is the Gita verse for "Worshipping demigods fulfils material desires, but for Moksha, one should worship Me."

Tags: krishna, gods, bhagavad-gita, identification-request

Where does in Bhagavad Gita, Lord Krishna say that:

*"Who worship demigods will get material desires, but to get moksha one must worship me only."*

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, Yes, I will retract my vote. Actually see the second Qn, which is a better duplicate. [What is the meaning of worshiping a demigod? And is it bad to worship a demigod? BG 4.12](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11676/what-is-the-meaning-of-worshiping-a-demigod-and-is-it-bad-to-worship-a-demigod). That exactly matches BG 4.12, hence you may close with that Qn.

Answer (score 1):

> > *"Who worship demigods will get material desires"*

Refers to following verses,

> BG 4.12 - Acting desirous of success, those who worship the demigods (*deva/raksha/preta/pitru*) here in this human world, the success happens quickly from those actions
>   BG 7.22 - Filled with that faith, that person engages in worshiping that form, and gets those very desired results as they are dispensed by Me alone.

Following concept can be found in many verses:

> > *"to get moksha one must worship me only."*

Prominent verses are:

> BG 4.10 - Many who were devoid of attachment, fear and anger, who were absorbed in Me, who had taken refuge in Me, and were purified by the austerity of Knowledge, have attained My state.  [Gambhirananda]
>   BG 9.25 - Those go to divine, who worship divine; Those go to ancestors<sup>@</sup>, who worship ancestor; Those go to ghosts, who worship ghosts; Those come to "Me", who worship "Me"
>   <sub>@-Sanskrit word is *pitru*, but it can also mean those with *Raksha* or demon quality; This verse co-relates to *sattva, rajas, tamas* of BG 17.4</sub>

Comment: Pitrus or demon-- What is that? Pitrus means the Manes not the demons.. is that ur inclusion or already there where u are quoting from?

Comment: @Rickross, Though it's referred as *Pitru*-s in that original verse, we have to take 2 meanings of it. One is normal good ancestors and others as bad/overzealous ancestors, which also can be referred as demons. Usually demons or even Pitrus are the product of *Rajas*. Here, "or" doesn't imply synonyms. It can be treated as "Either or". You may refer to the BG 17.4, which directly correlates to BG 9.25. To avoid confusion, I have edited the answer.

Comment: Is it ur translation or the translator also mentions in that way?

Comment: @Rickross, mine. Btw, there is no single or universal translator in Gita. One may choose a translator (e.g. Gambhirananda) or directly translate based on Sanskrit & online sources. The observations I posted above are mine based on researching the literature.

Comment: Ok yes there can be many.. i was asking about that translator translation of whom u are using for this answer..