# Does chanting name of Krishna in Kali yuga gives you moksha?

Tags: krishna, upanishads, moksha, kali-yuga, mukti

In Kalisantaran Upanishad it is mentioned that we can attain moksha by chanting the **Hare Krishna Mantra**.

But what I believe is Moksha means getting free from the shackles of Karma. 
Once we have nullified our Karma there is no longer need to be born again 
on mother earth.

Comment: Related and possibly already has an answer - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/who-gives-moksha

Comment: Moksha is something that lies at the end of life-chanting the name of Sri Krishna will put a person on the path that will lead to Moksha.In the journey of life, many other paths would also come, meaning one can also get derailed from that path.So, the efforts should continue till the end of life- and when a person reaches the end, the term Moksha would lose its very significance, for it would  have already been obtained.