# For getting Moksha , Whom should we be devoted to - Krishna or Shiva?

Tags: shiva, krishna, moksha

Some people say that for getting Moksha , we should be devoted to Krishna .

Others say that Shiva is the God of Moksha and we should be devoted to him for Moksha. Most hardcore ascetic sects like - Naga Sadhus are devotees of Shiv.

What is the truth ?

Comment: It is generally recommended that who wants to get moksha should worship Lord Shiva, but in gita krishna says that he also grants moksha

Comment: User tezz has beautifully [in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14374/17833) explained that both Visnu (Rama/Krishna) and Shiva are capable of granting Moksha. Further, even Devi is capable of granting Moksha as per Shaktas. And I'm sure as per ganapatyas Mahaganapati bestows it, so does Surya as per Sauras, and so does Brahmaa ji as per Hiranayagarbhas. Hinduism doesn't have a one person monopoly, as many would like to think!

Comment: Even Skanda is capable of granting moksha as oer as koumaras. ..