# Any Sanskrit verses that explicitly states that Ganesha, Surya and Hanumana grants Moksha?

Tags: moksha, hanuman, ganesha, surya, mukti

As per [various texts](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/who-gives-moksha), Shiva, Vishnu, Shakti have been told capable of granting Moksha.

Surya and Ganesha are part of the panchayatana smarta deities, in addition to the above three.

So along with them and Hanumana, I'm just curious to know if they arw said to grant Moksha?

Does any verses in any Sanskrit scripture, explicitly identify Moksha giving capabilities with Hanumana, Surya and Ganesha?

Comment: devotion to lord hanuman gives Ram bhakti which gives moksha

Comment: Above comment is right mentality. There is at least 2 shlokas stating that Vishnu alone can grant Moksha. Devotion to other deities are like rivers that ultimately lead to the sea of Vishnu. Think of it as admission to college. Only chancellor can ultimately grant admission, but only your school teacher who knows you can write you recommendation letter which chancellor reads. So, both are necessary, one is the path, one is the destination.

Comment: _Above comment is right mentality._ **No**. That's a right interpretation according to a specific sect @mar it's the plurality and diversified opinions of acharya of the same scriptures, why we have Atleast Six different "vadas" (Adavita, Visista, Dvaita, Shuddha, AbedaAbeda, etc.). There is a difference between a fact in scripture and interpretation. The above comment is interpretation m

Comment: By the way, I'm just looking for verses that says the above deity grants Moksha, not their interpretation. For example - In one of the Indrakrutam stotra on Lakshmi, she said to be "moksha-pradayani". So, I'm looking for those kinds of verse. Just verse. No interpretation.

Comment: @Vivikta - yes i'm aware u are not looking for interpretation. but it must seem obvious to anyone that there cannot be 2 distinct entities claiming the ability to bestow the ultimate benefaction. that would mean there are 2 supreme beings. no vadas, no darshans, not even any religion in the world accepts that there are 2 supreme beings. so i think we can all agree that there is only 1 supreme being, and only He can grant moksha, and it's only a question of determining who that is. all others claiming to grant moksha serve a necessary but subsidiary role.

Answer (score -1):

*Here's a partial answer.*

### 1. God Ganesha:

- In the Gaṇeśa Gītā from the Gaṇeśa Purāṇa, god Gaṇeśa himself proclaims thus -

> ॥ षष्ठोऽध्यायः - बुद्धियोगः ॥
>
> श्रीगजानन उवाच -
>
> ईदृशं विद्धि मे तत्त्वं मद्गतेनान्तरात्मना । यज्ज्ञात्वा मामसन्दिग्धं
> वेत्सि मोक्ष्यसि सर्वगम् ॥ १ ॥
>
> > Therefore, O king! **now listen about my attributes and elements,
> > knowing me as the all pervading truth, you'll be bestowed with Moksha.**
>
> English Translation based on Gita Press Gorakhpur's [Hindi Translation](https://archive.org/details/GitaSangraha/page/n50/mode/1up?view=theater)

---

---

### 2. God Surya:

- (a). Bhavishya Purana

> [Chapter 144](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D_/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5_%E0%A5%A7_(%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5)/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%AA%E0%A5%AA), Brahma Parva
>
> निष्कलस्तु सदा ज्ञेयः संस्थितस्तैजसीं कलाम् । हिमं घर्मं च वर्षं च
> त्रैलोक्ये कुरुते सदा । । १९ द्वितीया या तनुस्तस्य अक्षरं तत्परं पदम्
> । देवयानं तु पन्थानं कर्मयोगेन संस्थिता । 1.144.२०
> आदित्यसिद्धान्तरिताः साङ्ख्ययोगविदश्च ये । तेऽभिगच्छन्ति तत्स्थानं स
> मोक्षः परिकीर्तितः । । २१ निर्द्वन्द्वो निर्गमश्चैव तत्र गत्वा न शोचति
> । वेदेषु ब्रह्म वदन्ति ध्यायन्ते तत्त्ववेदिनः । । २२
>
> > When god Surya situated in his 'tejasvi kalâ', he's to be known as  Nishkala,
> > and bestows cold, heat and rain in the three worlds. In his second
> > kalâ, which is imperishable, is the gateway to the highest regions,
> > attained by the Karma Yogins following the godly path. **By the the
> > believers of Aditya-siddhanta and Samkhya Yoga also attain that
> > supreme region, which has been called Moksha**. That Moksha is bereft of
> > any duality and decay, known as Brahman in the Vedas, and meditated
> > upon by the 'tattva-vadins' too.
>
> English Translation based on the [Hindi translation](https://archive.org/details/BhavishyaPuranPart1/Bhavishya%20Puran%20Part%201%20/page/n595/mode/1up?view=theater) by Babulala Upadyaya

---

- (b). In the famous Surya-ashtkam, whose authorship is credited to god Shiva as per some [sources](https://www.siddhayoga.org/surya-devata/suryashtakam), Surya is told be the bestower of Moksha in Verse 8.

> [सूर्याष्टकम्](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_navagraha/sUryAShTakam.html)
>
> तं सूर्यं जगतां नाथं ज्ञानविज्ञान**मोक्षदम्** । 
>  महापापहरं देवं तं
> सूर्यं प्रणमाम्यहम् ॥ ८ ॥
>
> > 8. I bow to the Sun-god, Surya, the remover of great sins, who is the
> >    Master of the World, and **bestows knowledge, wisdom and Liberation
> >    (Moksha).**

---

---