# How many types of mukti are there?

Tags: moksha, mukti

I would like to know how many types of mukti are there. Also, is mukti the same thing as moksha? If not, what is the difference between those two?

If there are different types of mukti, is any type considered superior over the other?

Comment: Do the links in this question answer your question? http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2200/36

Comment: The Shiva Purana also talks about different types of Muktis towards the end chapters. Not exactly sure of the verse number.

Comment: Mukti i.e Moksha i.e a Soul leaving this temporal domain, for eternal "nothingness", for sat-chitt-ananda, for Sada-Shiva. Its of ONLY one type pal. But the paths to attain that could be many...and they are all equal...

Comment: Analogy 1. waves in the ocean, 2. the deep ocean itself and 3. water. The ocean in its depths is STILLNESS or absence of fluctuation. In waves the same ocean fluctuates up and down springing up waves into and out of existence. But there is a deeper Truth to both, both of them are 'Water' is it not? Similarly whether you are a temporary wave or in the depths of the ocean (i.e.) whether you are in a body (there are many types of bodies) or whether you are in the depths of stillness, all you have to do is realize you are 'Water' or you are 'Atman'. First is Jivan Mukti, second is Videha Mukti

Answer (score 1):

Mukti and Moksa mean the same. The meaning is to cast off, abandon, release. It is the process of releasing the soul from the material bondage and hence the common word in english is liberation.

Different kinds of liberation are discussed in [Srimad Bhagavatam Canto 3, chapter 29, verse 13](http://www.vedabase.com/sb/3/29/13)

> A pure devotee does not accept any kind of liberation — salokya,
>   sarsti, samipya, sarupya or ekatva — even though they are offered by
>   the Supreme Personality of Godhead.

In regards to if one is considered to be higher than the others it depends on who you ask. A personalist(Vaishnava) doesn't desire ekatva, merging into the existence of the Supreme Lord or impersonal Brahman. From a Gaudiya Vaishnava perspective there are different mellows, rasas, a devotee exchanges with Lord. The mellow of servitude, friendship, parental and conjugal. It is said that the mellow of conjugal relationship like in the case of Radha and Krishna constitutes the highest and most intimate relationship with the Supreme Lord. Of course the nature of any relationship with the Lord is full of ecstasy and each devotee thinks himself to be an insignificant servant of the Lord and His servants, so a devotee doesn't think he is superior to others.

Comment: If he do not accept? Doesn't he get it?

Comment: He doesn't accept means it is in the sense of he doesn't hanker for it. A pure devotee doesn't aspire anything beyond His service even if it means to go to hell. Devotees like that are very rare. If the Lord wants the devotee to serve Him in Vaikhunta he will obey that.