# Does the state of Moksha differ for different sects?

Tags: moksha, terminology

In another question, I asked if Ajamila attained Moksha and the reply was "He attained the abode of Vishnu".  Is that only a Vaishnavite definition of Moksha?  What other definitions exist in scripture?

Comment: The definition of moksha in alll Vaishnava sects except the Varkaris (who believe in attaining Nirvikalpa Samadhi as the ultimate) is attaining Vaikuntha/Goloka/Saketa.

Comment: Related: [How many types of mukti are there?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3933/277) and [Which Āstika schools mention the different types of Muktis?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2200/277)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it differ from sect to sect. In [Kashmiri Shaivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashmir_Shaivism) which is non dual Shaivism, enlightenment is not to attain any physical place but it is self realization. From [ParamArthsAra of AchArya Abhinavgupta](https://www.sanskrit-trikashaivism.com/en/abhinavagupta-s-paramarthasara-stanzas-59-to-62-trika-scriptures-non-dual-shaivism-of-kashmir/779) -

> मोक्षस्य नैव किञ्चिद्धामास्ति न चापि गमनमन्यत्र। 
>   अज्ञानग्रन्थिभिदा स्वशक्त्यभिव्यक्तता मोक्षः॥६०॥ 
>   In the case of Liberation (mokṣasya), there is neither (na eva kiñcid asti) an abode (dhāma) nor (na ca api) a going (gamanam) to another place (anyatra). Liberation (mokṣaḥ) (is simply) the manifestation (abhivyaktatā) of one's own (sva) Powers (śakti) by the piercing (bhidā) of the knot (granthi) of ignorance (ajñāna)||60||

Comment: This is a great verse. I have read it in Nityoshodashika Arnava Tantram's introduction.

Comment: @Rickross You might be interested in the scripture I have linked.