# How to get motivated to work if you follow Gita chapter 2, verse 47

Tags: bhagavad-gita

The Bhagwad Gita chapter 2, verse 47 states:

> karmaṇy-evādhikāras te mā phaleṣhu kadāchana
>
> mā karma-phala-hetur bhūr mā te saṅgo ’stvakarmaṇi

I am confused, how should one work, then how will I know if I have to do something if not for the results?
I will study because I want results or get better education in the long term; I will switch job if I want to be better paid; I will ask a girl out, if I want to have some form of relation with her; If I am leading an army, I will do some tactic to achieve something, which will later result in something bigger. If not for the result I will not do any work, which leads to `akarma` .

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31694/5696

Comment: Understand like this... Tomorrow is your exam and you are studying for it. Your preparation is not so good, so u start thinking about the exam paper now. What will happen? Anxiety will occur. It will slow you down, and remove ur focus.  If you are well prepared still you will think that I am well prepared I should take a break. This will also slow you down. Now, if you just focus on the book. Without much  expectations for exam. You won't be hurt if u it goes a little messy.... It will feel good if it goes well.

Comment: We can think about the results, without thinking about the results of our actions we can hit a wall. But once a clear decision has been taken. Stick to that. Don't over think.

Comment: God. Just wants to tell that don't overthink things.

Comment: And yes, after taking clear decisions or setting goal, just do action. Don't long for inaction or akarma .