# What is the source of Sat Chit Ananda mantra?

Tags: mantras, identification-request

> || Aum Sat Chit Ananda Parabrahma
>   Purushothama Paramatma
>   Sri Bhagavati Sametha
>   Sri Bhagavate Namaha ||

What's the source of this Mantra?

Comment: since you mention this shloka, pl. tell from where you came to know about it first? Any book, magazine, any ritual, or maybe something else?

Comment: There are 4 internal concious divisions, Ahamkaar, Manas, Buddhi and Chhit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samkhya study Samkhya. Out of these, only Chhit alone is truth and beautiful and also translates to Satyam Shivam Sundaram(Truth is beautiful/blissful) or Sat Chit Ananda

Comment: SO NO ONE KNOWS THE SOURCE!

Comment: Btw how do u know that this is called the Satchitananda Moola Mantra? This is probably not a scriptural mantra. @AkshayKumarS

Comment: @Rickross that's what am asking.  From where did this come? In a satsanga also this mantra was played.

Comment: No I am asking how u knew the name of the mantra? how u know that the mantra is so-called.. that's what I'm asking @AkshayKumarS

Comment: @Rickross It was played in satsanga where I went and hence I thought it was moola mantra of it. But now I get. Edited title!

Comment: Oaky thx for the info and yes that is exactly what I was asking.. it's nice that u hv understood my question finally :) @AkshayKumarS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chidakasha

> **Yoga Vasistha** speaks about the bhutākāsha – dealing with gross matter,
>   chittākāsha – dealing with mental concepts and chidākāsha with the
>   ātman . These are spaces projected by the mind but all spaces are
>   reduced to one, that is, to the ultimate space which is one’s own true
>   self.[3] Chittākāsha is the field of the mind which provokes a deeper
>   enquiry because there is in it still the duality of the 'seer' (drg)
>   and the 'seen' (drshya); this duality ceases to exist in chidākāsha
>   which is the field of Pure Consciousness viewed by the mind
>   non-casually. Different mental spaces are seen when the mind ventures
>   outwards to see all that which exists externally, but what already
>   exists externally exists within contained in the inner mental space
>   whose nature is different in different planes, and because
>   consciousness functions variously in varying dimensions depending upon
>   fineness of matter, the number of dimensions and the varying subtlety
>   of the mind. Chidākāsha is the result of Divine Ideation which makes
>   the world a mental projection that functions within time and space to
>   give itself a semblance of reality

Aatmastakam - Chidananda Roopah Shivoham Shivoham

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwusNKr6Pxk][1]

> Mano Budhyahankaar Chitani Naaham, Na Cha Shrotra Jihve Na Cha Ghraana
>   netre Na Cha Vyoma Bhumir Na Tejo Na Vayuh, **Chidananda Rupah** Shivoham
>   Shivoham
>
> Na Cha Praana Sanjno Na Vai Pancha Vaayuhu, Na Vaa Sapta Dhaatur Na Va
>   Pancha Koshah Na Vaak Paani Paadau Na Chopasthapaayuh, **Chidaananda
>   Rupah** Shivoham Shivoham

Tranlsation:

> I am not mind, nor intellect, nor ego, nor the reflections of inner
>   self (chitta). [more] I am not the five senses.I am beyond that. I am
>   not the ether, nor the earth, nor the fire, nor the wind.I am indeed,
>   That eternal knowing and bliss, Shiva, love and pure **consciousness.**

Chida(consciousness) is translated wrong by people as Chita(which is individual's)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chidakasha

and Hence it is **"Sat Chida Ananda"**

Comment: I am not asking what is sat chit ananda. The mantra is not found in authentic scriptures. So where this Mantra came from is my question

Comment: Yoga Vasista, check again

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Tat_Sat "Om Tat Sat" is another common mantra which means "Sat is represented by Om" and is explained by Yama to Nachiketa. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachiketa The sound Om! is the syllabus of the supreme Brahman
"The Atma, whose symbol is Om is the same as the omnipresent Brahman. Smaller than the smallest and larger than the largest, the Soul is formless and all-pervading."
Both mantras talk about same thing(Tat) that is "Truth/Sat/Chida" that is represented by "Om"

Comment: Chida is also called Turiya https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turiya

Comment: Chida is same as Brahman of Vedas