# What are the different paths of liberation which are recommended by the different sects of Hinduism?

Tags: vaishnavism, moksha, shaivism, sects, shaktism

In Shaivaism, the practice of meditation is recommended for liberation. What are the other ways to achieve liberation recommended by the other sects? I'm aware that there are different denominations in every sect. What are the methods of liberation they recommend and do they differ from the other denominations of the same sect. How and why?

Comment: In Shaivism also, meditation is not the only path for liberation. For eg. as I discuss in my [answer here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16594/why-is-lord-shiva-called-pashupati-who-are-the-pashus/16596#16596) there are various methods like Performing of Pashupat-Vrata, worshipping of Three Eyed Lord, Taking refugee on Lord etc... for getting Liberation....

Comment: See [What is the difference between thenkalai and vadakalai sects of Srivaishnavism.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2831/what-is-the-difference-between-thenkalai-and-vadakalai-sects-of-sri-vaishnavism/2835#2835) for vaishnavam.

Comment: Related [How many distinct independent paths are there to achieve Moksha?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2179/277)

Answer (score 3):

**A partial answer.**

> In Shaivaism, the practice of meditation is recommended for
>   liberation.

Its true that Yoga is a proven way of achieving Moksha but what you say is not entirely true also.

Even in the so-called "Shaivism" the "Bhakti MArga" seems to be the best way to attain liberation.At least ,Shiva Himself says so in the [Kurma Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/kurmapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=16) :

> Parama Shiva asserted:
>
> Naaham Tapobhirvividhairna Daanena na cheyjyayaa, Shakyo hi Purushair
>   **jaaturmutey Bhaktiamanuttamaam/**
>
> (**I am always realizable by Bhakti or Pure Devotion and not necessarily
>   by Tapasya, Daana or Charity and Yagnaas!)**

And further:

> Na madbhaktaa vinashyanti madbhaktaa veeta kalmashaah, Aadaavetat
>   pratigjaanam na mey bhaktah pranashyati/ Patram Pushpam Phalam toyam
>   madaaraadhana kaaranaat, Yo mey dadaati niyatah sa meyBhaktah
>   Priyomatah/
>
> My Bhaktaas would never be destroyed nor harmed but would be washed
>   off their sins as I took a vow that my Bhaktas are protected. **Bhaktas
>   are merely required to perform my Puja with utmost sincerity and offer
>   leaves, flowers, fruits and even water as I would be pleased).**

So,as you can see,Parama Shiva himself is speaking so highly of the "Bhakti MArga".

> Dhyanena maam prapashyanti kechirjjnanena chaaparey, Aparey bhakti
>   yogena chaaparey/ Sarveshaameva bhaktaamaamishtah Priyataro mama, Yohi
>   jnaanena maam nitya maadhaaraahyayati nyaayathaa/ Anye chaye trayo
>   Bhaktaa madaaraadhana kaankshinah, Teypi maam praapunanteva
>   naavartantey cha vai punah
>
> **Some persons seek my Darshan through Dhyaana or meditation, some by
>   Jnaana, but those by Bhakti are most dear to me and they would have no
>   re-birth**

Comment: What about the other sects?Also,is it possible to accept more than one answers?

Comment: @K Vickneshvara No, it is not possible to have more than 1 accepted answer.. however you can change accepted answer if another (better) answer comes:!

Comment: Linga Purana also says Bhakthi is best way to reach Lord Shiva.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think importance is given on the Bhakti way over others simply because the other paths like Yoga are extremely difficult to follow for everyone and not because of that they are ineffective..Yoga is the most effective way  i think..

Comment: @Rickross Yeah. Even i think Yoga is best way. In Bhakti, we can't verify our progress as verification is bit difficult though "Bhakti" removes all negative thoughts and attributes.  Yoga is clear and effective.

Answer (score 2):

In all Vaishnava traditions it is said that the path of *bhakti* is recommended as the best. And in doing *bhakti* there are several practices, of which it is said that *hari kirtana* or chanting holy names of Lord Vishnu and glorifying Him is the best, and it is especially recommended for this age of Kali or Kali yuga. There are many statements in the scriptures about that, and here is one of those verses, it's Bhagavatam 12.3.52:
https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/3/52

> kṛte yad dhyāyato viṣṇuṁ
>    tretāyāṁ yajato makhaiḥ
>   dvāpare paricaryāyāṁ
>    kalau tad dhari-kīrtanāt
>
> "Whatever result was obtained in Satya-yuga by meditating on Viṣṇu, in
>   Tretā-yuga by performing sacrifices, and in Dvāpara-yuga by serving
>   the Lord’s lotus feet can be obtained **in Kali-yuga simply by *hari-kīrtanāt* or chanting
>   the holy names of Lord Vishnu** (Hare Kṛṣṇa mahā-mantra.)"

Further explanation and additional quotes you can see in the commentary at the above vedabase link.