# What is the exact process to get Moksha?

Tags: moksha

Moksha is the aim of our life. But I don't find the exact way how to puruse Moksha. What is the process/blueprint to get Moksha ?

Comment: Does it help you https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2179/26679

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the most acceptable, and popular answer is - the blend of Gnana, Karma and Bhakti. However, there are controversies about this answer.

You must understand the meaning of Moksha first. Moksha is the release from the cycle of rebirth. Cause of Rebirth is the Karma. Karma creates bondage. And, till you have body, it is inevitable to do Karma. There are 2 ways to remove the bondage of Karma: do Karma without the expectation of reward OR offer the results to God. First solution is not practical (to implement in a 100% full-proof way). In second solution, you need to believe in God (that is Bhakti) which forces you to believe in something other than your Atma. That belief itself is Agnana. Till you have Agnana you cannot get Moksha.

Gnana is the most difficult path. But that is the only path which does not have any controversies. Even if you choose Bhakti or Karma path, the last stage before the Moksha is the Gyan, that is “I am the Bramha”.

All the above points are based on philosophy of Vedanta. It is beyond the scope of this space to cover the topic. Please read following to get started:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advaita_Vedanta,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvaita_Vedanta,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishishtadvaita

Note: These are millennium old debates. There are thousands of books written on it. Any discussion without the understanding of these philosophies will not help. Following any path without proper understanding will not lead to the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

**Kaivalya Upanishad.:**

> *हृत्पुण्डरीकं विरजं विशुद्धं विचिन्त्य मध्ये विशदं विशोकम् । अचिन्त्यमव्यक्तमनन्तरूपं शिवं प्रशान्तममृतं ब्रह्मयोनिम्॥ तमादिमध्यान्तविहीनमेकं विभुं चिदानन्दमरूपमद्भुतम् । **उमासहायं परमेश्वरं प्रभुं त्रिलोचनं नीलकण्ठं प्रशान्तम् ।** ध्यात्वा मुनिर्गच्छति भूतयोनिं समस्तसाक्षिं तमसः परस्तात्॥६-७॥*
>
> *6-7. At the center of the lotus of the heart, meditating upon that which is pure, without passion, clear, without sorrow, unthinkable, unmanifest, infinite in form, auspicious, peaceful, eternal and the cause of Brahma. Without a beginning, middle or an end, who is one, all pervading, of blissful consciousness, without form, wonderful, **seated with the goddess Uma, the Supreme Lord, the ruler, bearing three eyes, with a blue neck, ever peaceful** - by meditating upon Him (Somah/Shiva with Uma/Ardhanareshwara) the sages attain the source of all creation, the witness of all and that which is beyond all darkness.*
>
> *स एव सर्वं यद्भूतं यच्च भव्यं सनातनम् । **ज्ञात्वा तं मृत्युमत्येति नान्यः पन्था विमुक्तये॥९॥***
>
> *"He (Somah) alone is all that was, and all that will be, the Eternal; knowing Him (Somah), one transcends death; **there is no other way to liberation".***

I hope this clarifies all queries. Prd..