# Any easy way for moksha

Tags: bhagavad-gita, moksha, gita

See, I was an athiest who was enjoying lust and pleasure avoiding work and continuing this cycle. My problem increased with too much pending work, self hate and I just avoided people and cried alone in a room. I have negative thoughts and feeling of no worth. Then on social media I saw post like bhagvad gita solution of all problems. Now, I have read gita and overcome lust. But the life described in gita is much hard for me to attained like to free of desire but greedy or desires of ego meet me after 5-6 hours. Before, I avoided work. But now also I am working but not upto a standards given in gita. *If I try to live free of desire I find myself left with full of sadness.  I am feeling that this world is only for pain and I need to attain moksha .*

In short, I have defeated lust and anger . Now indulged in greed. But I require moksha. Please guide me how to be free of desire. Purify your mind of all evil thoughts and work till I attain moksha. (Karmyoga)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/how-many-distinct-independent-paths-are-there-to-achieve-moksha) question. But you should know that there is no 'easy' way.