# Is there an end to suffering?

Tags: karma, rebirth

We have met in the past Yuga. We are meeting again in this Yuga. We will meet again in next Yuga. And so on... Is there an end to this suffering , in general not just my own ,of taking birth and rebirth? If yes then will the next Yuga come to end forever?

EDIT: The answer seems to be No because Brahma repeats the cycle of birth and rebirth after a certain period. Note that the question was not about my birth or rebirth. Question was about our birth and rebirth. Since Brahma recreates the world there is no end to suffering in general. An individual may escape the suffering but collectively we will meet again in the next cycle. Therefore there is no end to the suffering.

Comment: "yogarato vaa bhogaratovaa sangarato vaa sangaviihinaH . yasya brahmaNi ramate chittam nandati nandati nandatyeva " So yes, there is an end to suffering.

Comment: Will the creation cease to exist ? Is this the last creation ?

Comment: your body is once again as in the prior yugas; but the jiva in your body in this yuga is a different jiva. The jiva in your body now can work to end its rounds of births and deaths in its present body or not. In the next yuga a different jiva will be in your body. Identify yourself with your jiva - not your body.

Comment: Moksha is end to your suffering.

Comment: [What is "Moksha"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/84/277)

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda can we stop the occurrence of this suffering for any jiva ?

Comment: When you get moksha (liberation from repeated births and deaths) you will stop suffering of material existence.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I understood. I will stop suffering after Moksha. But I seek Mosksha for everyone. Is it possible that Universe gets Moksha and there is no more the origin of suffering for anyone ever?

Comment: You can get moksha for yourself, not for others. Others are getting moksha or not, it can't be in your hand. But you can teach/guide them about importance of moksha and tell them ways of attaining moksha. THis is the least you can do for others. After listening from you it's their choice whether they want to do efforts for moksha or not. If after getting guidance from you about moksha if they choose not to do anything to get moksha then you can't do anything in that. Spreading awareness about moksha is only thing you can do for others.

Comment: Then there is no end to suffering. Somebody will always suffer due to the creation.

Comment: **Then there is no end to suffering** How is that? It's individual's choice whether they want to end their suffering or not. If they don't wanna end their suffering then what you or God can possibly do in that?

Comment: If you wanna drink a glass of water which is placed in front of you, then you have to do some efforts to drink it. You have to grab the glass and pick it up close to you mouth and drink it by yourself. I mean it's not like that the water will go in your stomach by it's own.. Similarly if you wanna get moksha then you have to do some efforts by yourself to get moksha. If one don't wanna do efforts of drinking water(moksha) then how he/she will overcome from his/her thirst(suffering)? If people don't wanna do efforts for moksha then how they will get moksha?

Comment: My question is that is there an end to suffering? We have met in this world and we have suffered. I will make an effort and I will attain Moksha. But what about the children ? How will they make effort ? They won't even understand the concept of Moksha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66693/discussion-between-rishabh-and-dheeraj-verma).

Comment: You can't seek moksha for everyone, you can seek moksha only for yourself. There is no collective moksha for the whole universe, it's not possible. But you can help people to understand the importance of getting moksha. Then those people can seek moksha for themselves.