# Is Brahm Gyan and Moksha same?

Tags: brahman, yoga, moksha, jnana

Brahm gyan, atma gyan and moksha are same? When do we get brahm gyan? Or does moksha means permanent staying in nirvikalpa avastha?

Comment: Moksha is a state attained through Brahm Gyan and as rightly guessed in the query is staying in Nirvikalpa state. Atman is the basic soul/cell which every individual has and take another form after death based on Karmas. https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2/verse/22 "Gita 2.22 As a person sheds worn-out garments and wears new ones, likewise, at the time of death, the soul casts off its worn-out body and enters a new one.". But knowledge of Atman, which even dead ghosts, spirits have, does not grant Moksha, only Brahm Gyan/Self-realization based on Vedanta does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brahmajnana is the same as atmajnana according to Advaita Vedanta and leads to moksha.

**Brahmajnana**

> The Vedanta system of philosophy posits Brahman as the origin of the
> entire universe including the inanimate nature and the living beings.
> The universe evolves out of it, it is sustained in it and involves
> back to it. Its essential nature is 'sat-cit-ananda',
> existence-consciousness-bliss. It is uncaused and eternal. It is also
> the very essence of the human beings. Since the human beings do not
> know this Brahman that is in them or behind them, they are undergoing
> a lot of suffering caused by the vicious circle of
> birth-death-rebirth, technically called 'samsara'. **Moksha or
> liberating oneself from the bondage of this samsara, is the ultimate
> goal of life.** This moksha can only be achieved by brahmajnana.
>
> Though the word 'jnana' means 'knowledge, 'brahmajnana' does not mean
> an intellectual understanding of Brahman. It is anubhuti or direct
> experience of Brahman, not only as the substratum of the entire
> creation, but also as the innermost core of oneself. Once this direct
> experience comes, there will no more be any identification with the
> body-mind complex which alone was responsible for samsara.
>
> In order to get this experience, one has to cultivate **sadhanacatustaya**
> first. This is to be followed by approaching a competent spiritual
> preceptor from whom one has to listen (sravana) to the Vedantic
> truths, reflect (manana) upon them and meditate (nidhidhyasana) upon
> them. This will ultimately lead to brahmajnana or direct experience of
> Brahman - often equated with atman, the Self - and result in moksha.

**A concise encylopaedia of Hinduism by Swami Harshananda**

Brahmajnana is the same as atmajnana in Advaita Vedanta since Brahman is Atman according to this spiritual system. Brahmajnana is not the same as moksha but leads to moksha. Moksha means liberation from Samsara.

**Sadhanacatustaya** (fourfold discipline of Vedanta)

> Works on Advaita Vedanta prescribe a mode of sadhana (spiritual
> discipline) which has two stages.
>
> The first or the preliminary stage is called sadhanacatusthaya or the
> fourfold spiritual discipline. These disciplines are: Viveka
> (discrimination); vairagya (renunciation); samadistaka ( the group of
> six, starting with sama or quietude) and mumuksutva (desire for moksa
> or liberation).

**A concise encylopaedia of Hinduism by Swami Harshananda**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be a partial Answer, *Brahma Gaayn*, *Atma Gaayn* and *Moksha* are three distict things. Both *Gaayn* are neccessary or occur as one transits towards *Moksha*. (Also see [Which Āstika schools mention the different types of Muktis?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2200/21353) and [What is "Moksha" in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/84/21353))

From the **Gaayn-Sankuli Tantra**:

> ॐकारादक्षरात्‌ सर्वात्वेता विद्याश्चर्तुदश ।
> मन्त्रपुजा तपो ध्यानं कर्माकर्म तथैव च॥
> षड़ङ्ग वेदचत्वारि मीमांसा न्‍यायविस्तरः ।
> धर्मशास्त्रपुराणादि एता विद्याश्चतुदर्दश ॥
> तावद्विजा भवेतु सर्वा यावद्‌ ज्ञानं न जायते।
> **ब्रह्माज्ञानं पदं ज्ञात्का सर्वविद्या स्थिरा भवेतु** ॥

> The birth of 14 *Vidyas*- *Mantra*, *Puja*, *Tap*, *Dhyan*, *Karma*, *Akarma*, 4 *Vedas*, *VedaAngas*, *Mimansa*, *Naya*, *DhrmhaShstra* and *Puran*. These 14 Take birth from '*OM*'. Unless one has the knowledge of these 14, one cannot gain *Brahmha Gyaan*. As one Gains it, all *Vidyas* become stationary and firm.

Describing it in a different way, one can say Knowledge of "Everything is one" is *Brahma Gyaan*, after which there remains no Distinctions between this and that. (There is a entire *Ullhasa* in *Nila-Saraswati tantra* as well in *Sarvollāsatantram* describing that 'oneness'. One can say its largely '*Advait*'). *Brahma Gaayn* is not expressable, I.e. one cannot make it *Uchishta*.

> उच्छिष्टं सर्वश्स्त्राणि स्वविद्या मुखे मुखे।
> नोच्छिष्टं ब्रह्मणो ज्ञात्तमव्यक्तं चेतनामयम ॥

> All *Shastras* have became *Uchishta*. All *Vidyas* move from one's mouth to others, But *Brahma Gyaan* is not *Uchishta*! It is cannot be Expressed and is Experienced.

From **Sarvollāsatantram 53rd Ullhasa**:

> शिव-ज्ञानं विना जीवः शिवोऽभूच्च न चेत् क्वचित् ।
> आत्मरब्रह्मोति संज्ञात्वा देवब्रह्मोति भावयेत् ॥

> without knowledge of *Jeeva* how can one get knowledge of *Shiva*? Without *Shiva* how can one reach '*I am Shiva*'? Unless the *AtmaBrahma* is understood, how can one know the *DevBrahma*? For *Siva*, the *Atman* is same as *Brahman*.